# Appending elements to parents that called the createElement() function

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a function that creates an element and takes the parameter of `element` (an object).

```
var createElement = function(element) {
  var newElement = document.createElement(element.type);
  var newElement_textNode = document.createTextNode(element.text);
  newElement.appendChild(newElement_textNode);
  element.parent.appendChild(newElement);
};
```

The only problem is I want to append the element to the element that called the function. For example:

```
var list = document.getElementById('ulList');
list.createElement({
    type: 'li',
    text: 'Another item'
});
```

My question is how do I append it to the element that called the function, in this case, the ul `list`

Comment: Why do you think that `How to solve this issue with my program` is an acceptable question title? Describe the question correctly in the title when you ask.

Comment: Good point... Any edit button around here?

Comment: ^^^^ Right above the comments and on the left

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a constructor that you can add methods to:

```
function DocNode(id) {
   this.domNode = document.getElementById(id); 
}

DocNode.prototype.createChildElement = function() {
    //add your code logic here
}

var list = new DocNode("testId");
```

Then list.createChildElement() can be called on any DocNode instance.

Comment: So if there was another element like a `div`, could I append a `span` to it like this:


`document.querySelector('div').createElement();`

Comment: Yep. The code above will work for any node in the dom. If you want to handle them differently, you can check the nodetype and proceed from there.